# How to update a field in User class using parse for ios?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am developing an app by using parse for backend. In the app, I have a registration module. User enters his email and password, and I send the data to parse and set the username temporarily to temp. On the next screen, the user is prompted to select a username, and I shall update the username in the backend accordingly. Now here's the problem: the field username's value doesn't get updated. These are few ways I have tried after looking up the internet.

```
//sharedclass is a singleton class, i save object id of the registered user to its attribute objectid.
NSString * objectID = sharedClass.sharedInstance->objectid;
NSLog(@"%@", objectID);
PFObject *pointer = [PFObject objectWithoutDataWithClassName:@"User" objectId:objectID];
sharedClass.sharedInstance->user.username = self.userName.text;
[pointer setObject:self.userName.text forKey:@"username"];
[pointer saveInBackground];
```

This one says that no object found. even though i get the objectID alright.
Then there is this one here:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Users"];
[query whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:objectID];//objectId is default parse field and objectID is the string i created
[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject * users, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {

        [users setObject:self.userName.text forKey:@"username"];


        [users saveInBackground];
        NSLog(@"Done");
    } else {
        // Did not find any UserStats for the current user
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }
}];
```

This one says no results matched the query.

Then I have this one:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Users"];

[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:objectID block:^(PFObject *username, NSError *error) {
    username[@"username"] = self.userName.text;
    [username saveInBackground];
}];
```

It has the same error that query has no matching results. How do I get the query right? Can someone explain why these queries aren't working?
this is how I retrieve the object id when user registration is successful

```
//objectid is a native string and objectId is the parse default field
sharedClass.sharedInstance->objectid = sharedClass.sharedInstance->user.objectId;
```

Here is screenshot of data on parse to understand the structure.

[image]

Comment: What is `objectID` when you first print it out? I just tested out some of your code with a Parse app of mine and it works perfectly, so the problem must be the object ID.

Comment: The NSLog gives kmdayobb9, objectID of the object created at that test. That'd be the object with username "nrkd" in the screenshot (i updated it manually from parse web). That's what's baffling. If objectID is correct why is query not matching any results? here is the console output to give you more insight. http://i61.tinypic.com/33z8dba.png

Comment: Your screenshot shows an object with an ID `Okmdayobb9` (notice the 'O' at the beginning) - was that a typo in your comment or in your code? Is the objectID in your app hard-coded or does it retrieve it from somewhere?

Comment: I edited the question with retrieval method for objectId. and it was a typo in my comment sorry about that

Comment: Try creating your query with `[PFUser query]` rather than `[PFQuery queryWithClassName:]`

Comment: Er, sorry if i am being too naïve but how would that work (i am new to parse and ios)? How can I initialise a PFQuery type object with [PFUser query]? Wouldn't that be wrong?

Comment: `[PFUser query]` returns a `PFQuery` object, e.g. `PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];`. It's the recommended way of querying `PFUser` objects. Docs: https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFUser.html#//api/name/query

Comment: Wow it worked. Thanks. I should read the documentation more. If you could psot it as an answer, i'd be able to accept it as the answer

Comment: Excellent, I'll post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Parse documentation for PFUser](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFUser.html#//api/name/query), and [this question on the Parse Q&A site](https://www.parse.com/questions/get-pfuser-in-pfquery-using-ios-api), `PFUser` is a special type of `PFObject`.

Rather than using `[PFQuery queryWithClassName:]`, you need to call `[PFUser query]` to retrieve a `PFQuery` object that can search for objects in your `Users` database - for example:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:objectID];
[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:....
```